# JSON passed from Python (Flask) into JavaScript is displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I am passing a JSON from a Python back-end into my front-end JavaScript where I'm running a webGL (three.js) animation. The JSON holds numerical values that determine what happens in the animation. My problem is that while I have a basic ajax request working, the JSON is being printed to the screen (in lieu of the animation) rather than becoming a variable I can iterate through to control aspects of the animation. The two halves of the call are shown below.

I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18835414/2441384) to this one before and got some great help, but am obviously still missing a piece of the puzzle. I've been reading docs and all sorts of sources, yet need a nudge in the right direction to finally get this working. Any help is appreciated!

In the python backend:

```
from flask import Response, json, render_template, jsonify
from app import app
from motifs import get_motif, get_motif_list

@app.route('/')
def index():
    motifs = get_motif_list(10)
#     The first version of the return below successfully sends data, yet it is printed to the 
#     screen, rather than being stored as data in a variable.
    return Response(json.dumps(motifs), mimetype='application/json')
#     This version of the return does not work:
#     return render_template("index.html", motifs = motifs)
```

In the JavaScript (note that the `console.log` sanity checks don't work - I have no idea why:

```
function foo() {
    var array_data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(JSON_array) {
        array_data = JSON.parse(JSON_array)["array"]
        console.log(array_data); // sanity check - doesn't work
    });
    return array_data;
};

var array = foo();
console.log(array); // sanity check - doesn't work
```

**UPDATE**

With help from the advice below, I'm pretty close to having this off the ground. The `JSON` is no longer printing to the screen (an issue caused by the Flask return), and I've solved a [multifunction callback issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23085889/2441384) I discovered along the way. However, I am now getting a `parsererror` from the `complete` `textStatus`. I think the problem now lays in the Python/Flask (see current code below). Thanks again for all who've helped!

Python/Flask (I think the problem is here - I'm a noob to Flask):

```
from flask import Response, json, render_template, jsonify
from app import app
from motifs import get_motif, get_motif_list

@app.route('/')
def index():
    motifs = get_motif_list(10)
    return Response(json.dumps(motifs), mimetype='application/json')

@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html")
```

The JavaScript (the data is returned by the Deferred object - used to solve a callback issue):

```
function getData() {

    var deferredData = new jQuery.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: deferredData.resolve(),
        complete : function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log("AJAX REquest complete -> ", xhr, " -> ", textStatus)}
    });

    return deferredData; // contains the passed data
};
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` possibly already coerce your data into json. start by debugging in the request.done function.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` *already decodes* the response for you.

Comment: Add the following callback to your ajax call and see what is logged to the console for textStatus.
    complete : function(xhr, textStatus){console.log("AJAX REquest complete -> ", xhr, " -> ", textStatus)}

Comment: @gromiczek Does requirement include calling `JSON_array` after `foo()` completion, outside `scope` of `foo` ? Does requirement include `JSON_array` defined as global variable ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 - thanks for your question. In the end I need to pass the JSON_array into another module in the code, so yes I'll need to call it outside the scope of `foo`, but in the end it will not be global. I'm taking a while to solved this problem because I've also realized need to learn how to handle multiple callbacks in my script. I have another asynchonous (non ajax/jquery) request I need to handle along with this call to the database.

Comment: @guest271314 - Thanks! Pardon my taking so long on this - I also put out a question on the callbacks issue - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23085889/2441384 , so I've been painstakingly trying to weave all these matters together. Oi!

Comment: @guest271314 - Ugh, it's still displaying to the screen instead of saving as a variable. I've even commented out all the javascript code related to this request and it's still displaying. This is fishy.

Comment: @gromiczek Not certain interpret accurately ? `window.array_data` ? Try without `return false` at `async()` ? Please post pieces tried. Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 - Sorry, the 'it' was the JSON object. I discovered that I needed to use the second return in python: `return render_template("index.html", motifs = motifs)` to stop that problem.

Comment: @guest271314 - added an update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50724/discussion-between-guest271314-and-gromiczek)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I had a lot of problems in my code above, several of which I had to debug in related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23118586/2441384) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23085889/2441384).

Among them were:

- in my original Flask `index()` function, it was dumping the JSON data to the screen because I was not rendering the `index.html` template anywhere.
- I had matching routes (`'/'`) and function names (`index()`) in the Flask functions
- As mentioned in the comments I did an unnecessary double parsing of the JSON with `dataType: json` and `array_data = JSON.parse(JSON_array)`
- the return from this asynchonous function always came up undefined because it was referenced before the call had resolved
- in my later update to a Deferred object, the `success` property should have read: `success: function(data) { deferredData.resolve(data);}`

So, after all those fixes, here is the functioning code!

**Flask/Python:**

```
from flask import Response, json, render_template, jsonify
from app import app
from motifs import get_motif, get_motif_list

@app.route('/ajax')
def ajax() :
    motifs = get_motif_list(10)
    return Response(json.dumps(motifs), mimetype='application/json')

@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html")
```

**JavaScript:** (note: this is the `foo()` function in my question above)

```
function getData() {

    var deferredData = new jQuery.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
            deferredData.resolve(data);
            },
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log("AJAX Request complete -> ", xhr, " -> ", textStatus);
            }
    });

    return deferredData; // contains the passed data
};


// I used the Deferred structure below because I later added Deferred objects from other asynchronous functions to the `.when`

var dataDeferred = getData();

$.when( dataDeferred  ).done( function( data ) {
    console.log("The data is: " + data);    
});
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. But, in my case, I am using plain JavaScript. So could you please help me how to use `Deferred` in plain JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript:

```
function foo() {
var array_data;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/",
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(JSON_array) {

    /*JSON_array is already parsed and it is an object..*/

    array_data = JSON.parse(JSON_array)["array"]
    /* ^ I belive you dont have to do this ^*/

    console.log(array_data);
    /* ^ change this to console.log(JSON_array);*/
});

return array_data;
/* ^ change this to return JSON_array;*/
};
```