# How to read a HTML table specific row and use the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table created and I want to read the value in cell and use it in a javascript.. Can anyone please suggest how to do this...

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr id="1">
        <td> pue </td>
        <td> 2.86 </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var PUIDValue = document.getElementById("pue").value;  
    var chartData1 = [
            {
                "category": "Evaluation",
                "excelent": 20,
                "good": 20,
                "average": 20,
                "poor": 20,
                "bad": 20,
                "limit": 78,
                "full": 100,
                "bullet": PUIDValue
            }
        ];
```

Comment: Its not part of your question so I wouldnt put it in the answer section, but jQuery makes tasks like this much easier... $($("table1").find("tr")[0]).find(td)[1].innerText, or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the size and which data you expect to use, but you could convert your table to a javascript array and then get the values from there.

Here is an example: [Convert html table to array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579721/convert-html-table-to-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
mainTr = document.getElementById('1'),
firstTd = mainTr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]
```