# Chrome querySelector() of a table into an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using the chrome dev tools and console, I want to create an organised table or array from the HTML table in the console. What I have so far returns a long string of all the span elements:

```
$('tbody > tr > td > span').text();
```

Would someone be able to educate me as to how I can create an array of each row in the HTML table?

*(site for ref: https://www.copart.com/lotSearchResults/?free=true&query= as you can see there's no class's or id's on any of the elements in the table)*

EDIT: table structure as requested in comments

```
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1997</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">45</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1998</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">40</span>
</tr>
...
```

I'd like to output an array like so:

```
[1997, FORD, 45]
[1998, FORD, 40]
...
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. What does the original HTML table look like? (show a concise example in the question, don't just link to a different page) What do you want the resulting data structure to look like? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? "*How [can I] create an array of each row in the HTML table?*" `$$('tbody > tr')` would be a good start but without more details, I'm not sure where you'd go from there.

Comment: It's not really that vague... the structure is pretty simple, table rows with table cells, I would like to print the value of each row in an array. I'll update my question if it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert html table to array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579721/convert-html-table-to-array-in-javascript).

Comment: looks like a `jquery` question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the site, you're going to have to explain a little more what you expect the output to look like. You've got images, some buttons, ratings and standard text to work with, so you'll need some additional logic to sniff that stuff out.

But, **generally speaking**, this is a good starting point on how to take a given HTML Table and convert it into an array of objects. The assumption in this example is that your `table` includes the `thead` and `tbody` format. If it doesn't, that can be removed from the code.

In addition, I would also point out that if you're just trying to download some data and don't really need a 'permanent solution', you should look into web scrapers such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en)

```js
const htmlToArray = (tableElement) => {
  const thead = tableElement.querySelector('thead');
  const tbody = tableElement.querySelector('tbody');
  // Assumes there's only one header row
  const columns = thead.querySelectorAll('tr th');
  const columnNames = [];
  columns.forEach( c => columnNames.push(c.innerText));
  const result = [];
  const bodyRows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
  bodyRows.forEach( r => {
    const tds = r.querySelectorAll('td');
    const obj = {};
    tds.forEach( (td, idx) => {
      obj[columnNames[idx]] = td.innerText;
    });
    result.push(obj);
  });
  return result;
};

const table = document.querySelector('table');
console.log(htmlToArray(table));
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data4</td>
      <td>Data5</td>
      <td>Data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data7</td>
      <td>Data8</td>
      <td>Data9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! Answers my question perfectly, intend on using cheerio to scrape a site and wanted to be able to return an array in console. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The table itself has an id you can use.

`var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#serverSideDataTable tbody tr')`

This will find all `<tr>` elements (table rows) that are inside a `<tbody>` element (skips the `<thead>` which contains column names), which in turn must be inside of an element with id 'serverSideDataTable'.

Not sure what you want to do with the rows after that.

Comment: If you already know exactly how you're going to use the rows and just need to fetch them this answer is  fine. However it seems unlikely to me you wouldn't know how to fetch the rows but did know how to transform/use them. @mwilson has the better general answer and you should use it if you are unsure how to proceed after getting the rows.

Answer (score 1):

CTS_AE shows a great functional approach. Here's another functional solution using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) -

```js
const table =
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'), tr =>
    Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td'), td =>
      td.textContent
    )
  )

console.log(table)
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1997</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">45</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1998</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">40</span>
</tr>
</table>
```

For contrast, here's an imperative-style answer -

```js
const table = []

for (const tr of document.querySelectorAll('tr')) {
  const row = []
  for (const td of tr.querySelectorAll('td')) {
    row.push(td.textContent)
  } 
  table.push(row)
}

console.log(table)
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1997</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">45</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">1998</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">FORD</span>
<td><span data-uname="lotsearchLotnumber">40</span>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did not know about `Array.from`. Good answer! Much less code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of magic going on here.

I'm converting the `querySelectorAll` to an array using a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

> I'm doing this because [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList
>   which is not currently iterable with `map`; some transpilers/plugins
>   may allow this though.

Then I [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the values that I want on up and out.

```js
var trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')];

var data = trs.map(tr => {
  var tds = [...tr.querySelectorAll('td')];
  return tds.map(td => td.innerText);
});

console.log(data);
console.table(data);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1997</td>
    <td>FORD</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1998</td>
    <td>FORD</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Protip**: If you're looking to see the values more clearly in the console you can use the `console.table` to see it as a table as shown in the screenshot attached below.

[image: console logging data as a table]

Comment: Very concise, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John107 I also added a bit about `console.table` that you may find interesting or useful. It doesn't help gather the data, but if you have a two dimensional array of data it displays it nicely in the console.

Comment: @CTS_AE `console.table` is also nice for displaying arrays of objects :D

Comment: `map` belongs to `Array.prototype`, which has no relation to `NodeList`. You can however use `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr'), tr => { ... })` to skip the wasted iterations used to pre-populate the `trs` and `tds` arrays. Another option is to use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'), tr => { ... })` where `Array.from` accepts a mapping function as an optional second argument

Comment: `Array.from` is also a nice way to get an array, but still wasteful I believe as you say. ie: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))` edit: lol just saw you add it to your answer after refreshing, wasn't trying to bash :P